# How to ignore files with a specific extension with fast-glob?

Tags: glob, prettier

Prettier is using [`fast-glob`](https://github.com/mrmlnc/fast-glob) to resolve glob patterns to match the files to format. I would like to include all the files in the current directory but the ones ending with either `.php` or `.html`.

I've tried several patterns but none of them is working:

```
**/*.[^php,html]
**/*.!{php,html}
```

How can  I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
**/!(*.php|*.html)
```